# Right to Left text writing support in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I m building an application for Arabic and in this i want that i should write text from right to left in textbox but i can see only the option to align the text to left or right.

How can i get this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-to-Left text support is only available in the Windows Phone 7 framework for Mango (7.1), which will not be available to consumers until November(ish) this year.

You can download the current beta of the Mango tools from the [App Hub](http://create.msdn.com) and develop applications for Mango in advance of the consumer release. The documentation for the `FlowDirection` property is on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.flowdirection(v=VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Languages that support right-to-left are only introduced in the Mango update. You can't do it before then.